# Permanent Freezing 22.04

Tags: 22.04, freeze, amd-ryzen

I have an AMD setup. Gigabyte BS450M DS3H, Ryzen 5 3600 and a RX580. I used to use Linux until it stopped working somehow. It started to freeze randomly and permanently. Can't move cursor, anything. I tried to solve it back then but couldn't find a solution. Stopped using it and now I'm trying again. It doesn't matter the Linux distribution, if it's installed, if i'm in the installation or just trying it. It just freezes randomly but permanently.

I've run a memtest for about 10hours and no errors were found. I'm monitoring temps right now, and these are the logs of my fresh installed Ubuntu 22.04 freezed on first start up:

```
abr 06 13:33:25 Ryzen5 kernel: hdaudio hdaudioC0D0: no AFG or MFG node found
abr 06 13:33:25 Ryzen5 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:06:00.1: no codecs initialized
abr 06 13:33:27 Ryzen5 gnome-session-binary[1037]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
abr 06 13:33:27 Ryzen5 gnome-session-binary[1037]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
abr 06 13:33:35 Ryzen5 gdm-password][1520]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
abr 06 13:33:36 Ryzen5 systemd[1559]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
abr 06 13:33:36 Ryzen5 systemd[1559]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
abr 06 13:33:36 Ryzen5 systemd[1559]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
abr 06 13:33:36 Ryzen5 systemd[1559]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
abr 06 13:33:37 Ryzen5 gdm-launch-environment][906]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
abr 06 13:33:52 Ryzen5 pulseaudio[1568]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you verify the ISO you made the Live Media from? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: @David I did not. But this keep happening no matter which ISO i download. Not likely to have downloaded about 20 corrupted ISO from different distributions.